# convert json parameters to bson for UpdateOne in mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

I am trying to use `UpdateOne` of `mongo-go-driver` library but this method take bson document. I give it a interface parameter (json).

My question is to find best way to parse my json request to bson for updating fields dynamically. Thank you.

```
func (s Store) Update(id`enter code here` bson.D, d interface{}) (*mongo.UpdateResult, int32, string) {
    upd := bson.D{
        {
            "$inc", bson.D{
                d,
            },
        },
    }
    c, ctx, _ := getCollection(s.conn, s.dbName, s.collectionName)
    res, err := c.UpdateOne(ctx, id, d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return res, 500, "DATABASE ERROR: Cannot update document"
    }
    return res, 200, "none"
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: cannot use d (type inte`enter code here`rface {}) as type primitive.E in array or slice literal: need type assertion
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `bson.D` as third parameter of `UpdateOne`, at least according to [this tutorial](https://github.com/tfogo/mongodb-go-tutorial#update-documents).

So in your code you shouldn't pass `d`, but `upd` to the `UpdateOne` function:

```
func (s Store) Update(id`enter code here` bson.D, d interface{}) (*mongo.UpdateResult, int32, string) {
    upd := bson.D{
        {
            "$inc", bson.D{
                d,
            },
        },
    }
    c, ctx, _ := getCollection(s.conn, s.dbName, s.collectionName)
    res, err := c.UpdateOne(ctx, id, upd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return res, 500, "DATABASE ERROR: Cannot update document"
    }
    return res, 200, "none"
}
```